# Stacked fonts with different style in HTML table

Tags: css, html, html-table

Newbie in HTML and CSS here. I'm trying to make a table and in the cells I'd like to stack some text. 
E.g. The Cell "Name: John Smith" I'd like "Name:" and "John Smith" to be on two separate lines.

Now my problem is that I'd like the style of the texts to be different. So "Name:" should have a different font size, weight, etc. Than "John Smith".

Any help here? Here is some sample code.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name: John Smith</th>
    <th>Occupation: Data Scientist</th>
    <th>Date: April 2018</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The balise `<span></span>` can be used to wrap your text and change their style.

```
<th><span style="color: red">Name:</span><span style="color: blue">John Smith</span></th>
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvYBwz)

And going a bit deeper, you can add classes to these span.

```
<th><span class="th_title">Name:</span><span class="th_value">John Smith</span></th>

<style>
.th_title
{
color: red;
}

.th_value
{
color: red;
}
</style>
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqRayL)

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful. Do you know how to incorporate the line break? I tried using `white-space: pre;` as a CSS property for `td` but for some reason the second line is indented.

Comment: Set th_title to "display:block;" in the css

Comment: @JoeBringley You're welcome Joe. Daniel gave you a good answer for the line break. If your problem is solved, please validate the answer to close this post